# MS Access 2007: How can a csv file and its csv data be imported to a mdb table which has only column headings?

Tags: csv, ms-access-2007

Where the column headings are in the db and matched up with the file's csv columns.
I get 2 error message popups at the end of the importer wizard:
1)  squash the existing table 'table_name' and a yes/no selection.  I select 'yes', then
2) "impossible to replace the table 'table_name' "

The CSV file matches with the table in column number, it only contains the data to fill the rows, it does not contain the headings.

Comment: How are you doing the import? With code? With a wizard? Please add some detail.

Comment: Replying "no" just ends the import wizard

Comment: Depending how often this process needs to be carried out, could you not open the CSV with Excel, select and copy the rows; and paste them into the Access table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved using excel.

Sorry, I'll try to think about what I'm really looking to do before posting next time - I really just wanted to match up the data from the CSV file to the headings from the Access table.  I was able to import both into excel to match them up, thanks to those who tried to help.